# Get parent node value for each specific child

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to return a matrix as follows :

- key1 -> Val1
- Key1 -> Val2
- key2 -> Val1
- key2 -> Val2
- key2 -> Val3

In other words, for each CC node I would like to return only the previous AA nodes.

Can you please help me getting the right xslt 1.0 code?
XML example :

```
<parent>
    <AA>Val1</AA>
    <AA>Val2</AA>
    <BB>
         <CC>key1</CC>
    </BB>
    <AA>Val3</AA>
    <BB>
         <CC>key2</CC>
    </BB>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you could do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parent/BB/CC"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CC">
    <xsl:variable name="currentCC" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="preceding::AA">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($currentCC,' -&gt; ',.)"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26n1/1

**Edit**
To get only the last element, you could use:

```
  <xsl:template match="CC">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,' -&gt; ',preceding::AA[1])"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Amazing Thank you! Is there a way to extract only the last value for each key? example : Key1->Val2 ; Key2->Val2

Comment: thanks for that. 
I noticed that my code is showing onlu the values of key2. I am not sure why key1 values are not being displayed. Any idea please? should I add for each when applying template CC ?

Comment: @user1503496 Works fine for me : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS26n1/2